# notify-send not working on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, lxde, libnotify

I have `libnotify-bin` installed, yet when I type

```
notify-send "hello"
```

nothing happens. No error, no message
I have the necessary packages:

```
# dpkg -l | grep notify
ii  libnotify-bin
ii  libnotify4:amd64
```

what could be the problem?

I am using LXDE on Debian Wheezy

## UPDATE:

While the solution suggested by @Anthon works (install `notification-daemon`), I am not sure whether that is the "best" solution. I was expecting that it is enough to have `libnotify-bin` and `libnotify4` and `dbus` installed. Inedeed, on my other machine, notify-send works without `notification-daemon`.

Can somebody please clarify whether `notification-daemon` is necessary or not ?

Comment: @don_crissti - yes, the other machine has the same setup: Debian Wheezy + LXDE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your notification daemon has probably not been started. Try to start it by hand with:

```
/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
```

If you have a properly started daemon, you might have hit [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=747465), which causes the daemon to crash.

Comment: OK, I did not have `notification-daemon` installed. When I install it and start, then notifications work. It is strange, however. On my other machine the notifications work without `notification-daemon`. I thought it is using `dbus`.

Comment: I currently have no machine with LXDE running anymore, not sure if it was using DBUS or not.